# How to change the color of the inner slide in a RangeSlider (JavaFX)?

Tags: css, javafx, controlsfx, javafx-css

I'm trying to change the css of the [RangeSlider](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/RangeSlider.html)

I am using this maven dependency in integtare it in my FXML file

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
        <version>8.40.12</version>
    </dependency
```

its id in the fxml file is :

```
<RangeSlider fx:id="rangeSlider"
```

I injected it in the controller with:

```
@FXML
private RangeSlider rangeSlider
```

then I set an Id to change its appearence with CSS :

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb){

    rangeSlider.adjustHighValue(30);
    rangeSlider.setId("rangeSlider");
}
```

and in the CSS side :

```
#rangeSlider .thumb {
    -fx-background-color: #2196f3;
}

#rangeSlider .track{
    -fx-background-color: #151928;
}
```

I can't figure out how to change the inner blue color

[image]
any help much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node responsible for the color between the thumbs is a `StackPane` with the style class `range-bar`. The `-fx-background-color` defaults to `-fx-focus-color`, but you could override this property:

```css
#rangeSlider .range-bar {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

---

If you want to take a look at the details, refer to the [`RangeSliderSkin.initRangeBar`](https://github.com/jinghai/controlsfx/blob/master/controlsfx/src/main/java/impl/org/controlsfx/skin/RangeSliderSkin.java#L261) code and/or [`rangeslider.css`](https://github.com/jinghai/controlsfx/blob/master/controlsfx/src/main/resources/org/controlsfx/control/rangeslider.css).